# alternative to many cfif/cfelseif tags

Tags: coldfusion

I've got a cfldap query that returns the distinguishedName's associated with a user. Within the users distinguishedName's, there is an OU that identifies that users region, I'm using the region as a variable that populates a select box containing the names of our facilities in that region.

Right now I'm doing

```
<cfif distinguishedName = A>
  <cfset region = A>
<cfelseif distinguishedName = B>
  <cfset region = B>
```

etc. etc.

for all 7 regions, and while that works, I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: case/switch is often used in this situation.

Comment: Why not set region = distinguishedName ?

Comment: Another way would be to create a struct with the keys and values, but if you're simply setting the same value into another variable then what @Abram says is the correct way to do.

Comment: Lot's of good suggestions, thanks. I played around with case/switch, couldn't get it to work, probably had the syntax wrong. I'll work on the struct idea, been meaning to learn how to do that. Only been working with coldfusion for about a year now, so still lots to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: @toleolu Case/Switch isn't any better for minimizing this sort of code/task than cfif. (though there are definitely *cases* where it is)

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that your example is a poor one, and you're not really doing this:

```
<cfif distinguishedName eq A>
    <cfset region = A>
<cfelseif distinguishedName eq B>
    <cfset region = B>
```

(etc), because that doesn't make a great deal of sense. As Abram suggested, if you *are* doing that, then simply:

```
<cfset region = distinguishedName>
```

I'm guessing the value that you are setting for `region` is *not* the same as the DN.

I think Matt's kinda on the right track suggesting a struct which maps the `DN` to the `region`, but I'd make an RegionMapper CFC instead, holding a struct of the mappings internally, and providing `getRegionForDn()` method (I'm not sold on that name, but you know what I mean), which returns the appropriate region if there is a mapping, or a default or a sensible exception as appropriate if there is no match.

Comment: No I just used that to try to explain what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the distinguished Name will always come back as only "OU=Foo", then you can just do a ListLast() and be done.

```
Region = ListLast(distinguishedName,"=");
```

You may not have this issue, but if the distinguishedName ever is part of a full DN like

```
CN=John Doe,OU=Oahu,DC=foo,DC=bar
```

you will need to do a little more to get the OU value.  You could use some of the built-in List Functions like ListToArray() and then find the value.  You would need to be aware of commas inside the OU though like "OU=foo\,bar".

```
DN = "CN=John Doe,OU=Oahu,DC=foo,DC=bar";
rdnsArray = ListToArray(DN,",");
pos = ArrayContainsNoCase(rdnsArray,"OU=");
Region = ListLast(rdnsArray[pos],"=");
```

Another option, maybe a bit of an overkill is to use Java to get it.

```
LDAPName = CreateObject("java","javax.naming.ldap.LdapName").init(JavaCast("string",distinguishedName));
RDNS = LDAPName.getRdns();
for(rdn in RDNS){
    if(rdn.getType() == "OU"){
        Region = rdn.GetValue();
        break; //breaks when found
    }
}
```

I second Adam's suggestion of putting this in a function

Answer (score 0):

First, as Matt says, you can do something like this, as an example.

```
<cfset LangNames = {CF = "Cold Fusion", PHP = "Personal Home Page", ASP = "Active Server Pages"}>
<cfif structKeyExists(LangNames,inputName)> // where inputname is a variable with the value cf, php, html*, etc
  <cfset LangFullName = LangNames[inputName]>
<cfelse>
  Key doesn't exist, can use this section to report an error.
</cfif>

* You'll notice html isn't in the list, so it would fail this check.
```

It's about the shortest way to do it. The nice part about cold fusion keys is that they don't have to just be alphanumeric. You can have struct keys named `<b>` if you want.

```
<cfset tagPurposes = {"<b>" = "Bolds text", "<i>" = "Italicizes text"}>
<cfoutput>#htmleditformat(structkeylist(tagpurposes))# #tagpurposes["<b>"]#</cfoutput>
```

I'm not advising you go overboard with wild variable names. I tend to stick to alphanumeric, but this is an example, because there are occasions, like yours, where developers like to take exactly the method you're seeking.

Comment: I recommend using this same technique.  When the structs are more complex and the creation sort order is to be retained for collection looping, I prefer using a java LinkedHashMap. (WARNING: keys are case-sensitive.) Letters = CreateObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init(); Letters["A"] = {phonetic="Alfa", pronounced="AL-FAH"}; Letters["B"] = {phonetic="Bravo", pronounced="BRAH-VOH"}; (NOTE: Looping over a regular struct will results in random-ordered keys.)

Comment: The distinguished name comes back as OU=Oahu, or OU=Maui, etc. so the cfif and cfifelse was cfif result.distinguishedName=OU=Oahu cfset region=Oahu. Then I would repeat that for every region, Just wanted to clear that up. The region variable is used to set the variables of a pull down menu of the facilities of that region. The facility the user selects is then used to list email Distribution Groups for that facility. Had to go this route because of the way AD is set up, don't have any control over that. Thanks for the examples, I'll give those a shot, lot cleaner than what I am doing. Mahalo